# MySQL: optimise the query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, case

I using the the below query to make some time calculation. I am not shure, if this way is the best one. Do you know a better way to get the same result?

```
Select
((Time_To_Sec(TimeDiff(arbeitszeit.ezeit, arbeitszeit.szeit)) / 3600) -
arbeitszeit.arbzpause) AS Netto,
(CASE
WHEN ((arbeitszeit.szeit >= arbeitszeit.gs) AND (arbeitszeit.ezeit <=
arbeitszeit.ge) AND (DayOfWeek(arbeitszeit.arbzstart) <> 1) AND
(DayOfWeek(arbeitszeit.arbzstart) <> 7) AND (arbeitszeit.arbszart <>
'Feiertag')) THEN ((Time_To_Sec(TimeDiff(arbeitszeit.ezeit,
arbeitszeit.szeit)) / 3600) - arbeitszeit.arbzpause)
WHEN ((arbeitszeit.szeit < arbeitszeit.gs) AND (arbeitszeit.ezeit >
arbeitszeit.gs) AND (arbeitszeit.ezeit <= arbeitszeit.ge) AND
(DayOfWeek(arbeitszeit.arbzstart) <> 1) AND
(DayOfWeek(arbeitszeit.arbzstart) <> 7) AND (arbeitszeit.arbszart <>
'Feiertag')) THEN ((Time_To_Sec(TimeDiff(arbeitszeit.ezeit, arbeitszeit.gs))
/ 3600) - arbeitszeit.arbzpause)
WHEN ((arbeitszeit.szeit >= arbeitszeit.gs) AND (arbeitszeit.szeit <
arbeitszeit.ge) AND (arbeitszeit.ezeit > arbeitszeit.ge) AND
(DayOfWeek(arbeitszeit.arbzstart) <> 1) AND
(DayOfWeek(arbeitszeit.arbzstart) <> 7) AND (arbeitszeit.arbszart <>
'Feiertag')) THEN ((Time_To_Sec(TimeDiff(arbeitszeit.ge, arbeitszeit.szeit))
/ 3600) - arbeitszeit.arbzpause) ELSE 0 END) AS IST,
If((arbeitszeit.arbszart = 'Kompensation'),
((Time_To_Sec(TimeDiff(arbeitszeit.ezeit, arbeitszeit.szeit)) / 3600) -
arbeitszeit.arbzpause), 0) AS Komp,
arbeitszeit.arbzgrpid AS arbzgrpid,
arbeitszeit.abszsvisor AS abszsvisor
FROM arbeitszeit
JOIN users ON arbeitszeit.arbzusrid = users.usrnr
ORDER BY arbzid
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "MySQL: optimise the query" -> optimise the formatting :-)

Comment: Improvements for working code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/